# FOSRestBundle: show my custom exception message

Tags: php, symfony, exception, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to add a custom control of exceptions in FOSRestBundle but it seems to ignore my custom messages (the status code of the response is ok).

I have:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "User {$id} not found");
```

But get this json response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

So I don't find the way to show my custom message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also throw you own exception using the following configuration:

```
fos_rest:
    exception:
        codes:
            'My\Custom\NotFound\Exception404': 404
        messages:
            'My\Custom\NotFound\Exception404': true
```

Provide a custom message in your own exception class and it should work as expected.

Comment: I tried this and still get the default http message for exceptions in prod environment (such as Bad Request for a 400), both with my custom exception class or with Symfony's. It works without problem in dev. Did I miss any other configuration to do?

Comment: Try setting exception_controller under twig section in config.yml:
'FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction'

Comment: Thanks, setting this option in the `twig` section did it. For some reason the documentation says it can be set in the `fos_rest.exception` section, but it doesn't actually accept it.

Comment: Personally, i add to remove var/cache directory to make it works ! Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

On the [View Layer documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-the-view-layer.md): `If you don't like the default exception structure, you can provide your own implementation.`

```
class ExceptionWrapperHandler implements ExceptionWrapperHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function wrap($data)
    {
        // we get the original exception
        $exception = $data['exception'];

        // some operations
        // ...

        // return the array
        return array(
            'code'    => $code,
            'message' => $message,
            'value'   => $value
        );
    }
}
```

```
// config.yml
fos_rest:
    view:
        exception_wrapper_handler: Namespace\To\ExceptionWrapperHandler
```

Comment: It's not working, I'm not working with forms or views, I return a JsonResponse with the data always. Maybe this solution doesn't work without views?

Comment: This is something related to the views, indeed. Why aren't you using views ? This does not suit your needs ? Because FOSRestBundle process JSON response as a view.

Comment: My api is only json so I work with input data as simple parameters (not `FormType`) and return always a `return new JsonResponse($array_data);`, when an exception occurs I `throw new HttpException(404, "User {$id} not found");` I was in a hurry to deploy so made it more straight

Comment: You can return only JSON if you want with FOSRest. You should take a look to the documentation (and the view layer). It can do what you want :). But anyway, this solution should work, FOSRest use this to process exceptions.

Comment: Does not do anything =(   maybe this feature has been removed but documentation hasn't been updated?

Comment: Turns out it is [only possible to do if you are using the JMS Serializer Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/4-exception-controller-support.html).

Answer (score 4):

To display your custom exception message (simply into app/config/config.yml):

```
fos_rest:
    exception:
         messages:
            Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: true
```

Comment: Personally, i add to remove var/cache directory to make it works ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is, to set the `debug` flag in the fos_rest config like this:

```
fos_rest:
    // ...
    exception:
        // ...
        debug: true
```

This will show the actual exception message for **all** exceptions. Obviously this could be a security risk, so use it with caution.