# Symfony, Exception message in production

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a RestApi with Symfony2 and https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

I log all errors, and i send exception if there is a problem.

For example :

```
throw new AccessDeniedException("This is a message for my error");
```

When i am on dev mode, i can retrieve my message `This is a message for my error` in the response, but in production mode, i only have `{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}`

How can i edit the message in this error in production mode ?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979499/fosrestbundle-show-my-custom-exception-message/24989854?noredirect=1#comment38893251_24989854). Did you clear the cache ?

Comment: Hum, yes it's a good idea, but it doesn't work for me..

Comment: Really down vote ? Do you know how to do this thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ExceptionController-related options might interest you. Did you read [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/4-exception-controller-support.html)?

Comment: The given link returns a 404 now, can you update it?